# jQuery hide a div if the child div doesn't contain a class

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove two `<div>`s from the page if information exists within a child class "price" of parent class ".summary entry-summary"

I've first tried checking for the parent class of "woocommerce-Price-amount amount" (Price) but due to it's requirement on every page to check the database that won't work.

I've attempted checking within the div for $ since that will only populate in this div if the info from the database has populated, but it will still remove the divs on pages this doesn't exist on.

```
// Checks page for price on item div, 
// if price exists then the page will hide the "For price call (phone number)"
// second .hide will hide "Contact company for pricing information"

jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
$(".summary entry-summary").hasClass("woocommerce-Price-amount amount")
    $(".well").hide(),
    $(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description").hide();
});
```

The code is supposed to remove two divs only if "woocommerce-Price-amount amount" exists within parent div .sumary entry-summary.

The code removes the two divs even if the child class doesn't exist.

EDIT: I've updated the code to include an if statement and also added my closing ; the code is still having the same issue.

Comment: put your hasClass test in an if statement, and make the comma a semicolon after hide().  Have not looked closely at this, but do that to begin

Comment: Javascript will add an *implied* `;` at the end of the line (after your `.hasClass()`) where it thinks there should be one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're checking for a class then hiding other elements based on that check.  You're missing the `if` in the supplied code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($(".summary entry-summary").hasClass("woocommerce-Price-amount amount")) {
        $(".well").hide();
        $(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the divs are generated you need to use a delegate. Target the parent container in which you are populating the divs from database then set a delegate on it that with check if the divs within it static or generated has the required class or not then perform the corresponding action #cheers

Comment: use on instead of delegate

Comment: on is actually a delegate

Comment: Yeah you are right I wasn't saying he should use .delegate() method though the whole process of attaching an event listener on a parent and then bubbling when the child is clicked is known as delegate all the same you are right sir.